# Am I using my hand gripper properly?

Tags: grip-strength

I've just started using a hand gripper and I'm a skinny guy so I use an adjustable gripper at 10kgs which sometimes is difficult to close. I've seen a lot of people say that you have to use it a lot to get good results, so I do 10 sets of 20 reps each hand per day. So am I doing it too much or should I do more?

Comment: You really need to mention how often you're doing these 10 sets (every day? every week?), and how hard it is to complete the 20 reps. Does the 20th rep feel much, much harder than the first, or do all the reps feel the same?

Comment: I do 10 sets every day and in between them I take irregular breaks cuz my pinky finger is bruised a bit and yes sometimes 20th rep feels much harder and usually I'm not able to close it by few millimeters. Mostly all the reps feel the same.